# Microsoft Access Calculation

Tags: ms-access

I have this data in my MS-Access.

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpPxE.png)
[image]

***I want to Add an “Hourly Rate” field to the second table which automatically calculates the hourly rate according to the following requirements:

a. If the Employment Type is “Full Time”, then Hourly Rate = Base Rate

b. If the Employment Type is “Casual”, then Hourly Rate = 1.25 x Base Rate

Answer (score 0):

Go to the design view of the table and add a new calculated column. Then you can define an appropriate expression in the general options. Access columns support if-funktions.